# How do I access data within data in Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, analysis

I have a Python dict in this format:

```
test_scr = { 
    "visited_pages" : [ { 
          "visited_page_id" : { 
              "$oid" : "57d01dd3f1a475f7307b23d9" 
          }, "url" : "google.com", 
         "page_height" : "3986", 
         "visited_on" : { 
             "$date" : 1473256915000 
          }, "visited_page_clicks" : [ { 
                "x" : "887", 
                "y" : "35", 
                "page_height" : "3986", 
                "created" : { 
                    "$date" : 1473256920000 
                 } 
            } ], 
         "total_clicks" : 1, 
         "total_time_spent_in_minutes" : "0.10", 
         "total_mouse_moves" : 0 
      }, { 
          "visited_page_id" : { 
              "$oid" : "57d01dddf1a475a6377b23d4" 
          }, "url" : "google.com", 
         "page_height" : "3088", 
         "visited_on" : { 
             "$date" : 1473256925000 
          }, "visited_page_clicks" : [ {
                "x" : "888", 
                "y" : "381", 
                "page_height" : "3088", 
                "created" : { 
                    "$date" : 1473256934000 
                 } 
             },{
                "x" : "888", 
                "y" : "381", 
                "page_height" : "3088",
                "created" : { 
                    "$date" : 1473256935000 
                 } 
             },{ 
                 "x" : "875", 
                 "y" : "364",
                 "page_height" : "3088",
                  "created" : { 
                     "$date" : 1473256936000 
                 } 
             },{ 
                 "x" : "875",
                 "y" : "364",
                 "page_height" : "3088",
                 "created" : { 
                      "$date" : 1473256936000 
                  } 
             }, {
                 "x" : "875", 
                 "y" : "364",
                 "page_height" : "3088",
                 "created" : {
                      "$date" : 1473256937000 
                  } 
             },{ 
                 "x" : "1347",
                 "y" : "445", 
                 "page_height" : "3088", 
                 "created" : { 
                      "$date" : 1473256942000 
                  } 
             },{ 
                  "x" : "259", 
                  "y" : "798", 
                  "page_height" : "3018", 
                  "created" : { 
                       "$date" : 1473257244000 
                  } 
             },{ 
                  "x" : "400", 
                  "y" : "98", 
                  "page_height" : "3088",
                  "created" : { 
                       "$date" : 1473257785000 
                  } 
             }],"total_clicks" : 8, 
                "total_time_spent_in_minutes" : "14.26", 
                "total_mouse_moves" : 0 
         }, { 
            "visited_page_id" : { 
                    "$oid" : "57d0213ff1a475a6377b23d5" 
            },"url" : "google.com",
            "page_height" : "3088",
            "visited_on" : { 
                    "$date" : 1473257791000 
            },"visited_page_clicks" : [ { 
                  "x" : "805", 
                  "y" : "425", 
                  "page_height" : "3088", 
                  "created" : { 
                        "$date" : 1473257826000 
                  } 
              }, {
                  "x" : "523", 
                  "y" : "100", 
                  "page_height" : "3088", 
                  "created" : { 
                        "$date" : 1473257833000 
                  } 
            } ], "total_clicks" : 2, 
            "total_time_spent_in_minutes" : "0.47", 
            "total_mouse_moves" : 0 
        } 
    }
```

I have to extract only X and Y values from the dict in this and store them in a matrix form in a data-frame.
Output should be something like:

```
X       Y
887     35
888     381
888     381
875     364
.        .
.        .
.        .
```

How can I do this?

Comment: @Yuvraj Jaiswal Why did you add that text???

Comment: @Psytho it was not letting me edit, "your post seems to have most part as code,add some more details". I frankly had no idea what to do. Can you suggest how can I rectify that?

Comment: Where does the dictionary come from? Just providing a random dictionary and asking how to extract values from it is not enough: you have to provide some context for your question. That will allow your readers to figure oout how best to help you. Formatting the dict properly is crucial btw: although people have edited your question to make things better, that is something that you should do yourself *before* asking the question. It is almost impossible to figure out the structure of  a dict if it is not formatted properly, particularly when it is a somewhat convoluted case, as this one is.

Comment: @YuvrajJaiswal - If you have comments or feedback for someone about their question, then post a comment under the question. Don't edit their question to include feedback (or add words that the OP never said). Those are invalid edits.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I did not intend to do so. But after I had cleaned up the massive dictionary, I was prompted to add more details (and not letting me submit the edit). Those were the only details I could think of since I had no idea about anything else. Pardon for that. Also, please edit to remove that part. I just intended to clean up the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dictionary is formatted pretty bad in this post, but I wrote up a quick little script which is able to loop through and get the x and y values from a dictionary.
You access dictionary values with the `dictionary["key"]` syntax. It will return the value or object stored for that key.

```
# Two lists to store the x and y values in    
x = []
y = []

# Store the visited_pages object in a list
visited_pages = test_scr["visited_pages"]

# Loop through all the pages
for page in visited_pages:
    page_clicks = page["visited_page_clicks"]
    # Loop through all the clicks for the page
    for click in page_clicks:
        # Add the x and y values to the lists
        x.append(click["x"])
        y.append(click["y"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using list comprehension

```
coords = [[click['x'],click['y']] for page in test_scr['visited_pages'] for click in page['visited_page_clicks']]
```

You can convert this to data-frame using a variety of techniques or re-shape them in the format you want.

Also, please format your code properly

Output

```
[['887', '35'],
['888', '381'],
['888', '381'],
['875', '364'],
['875', '364'],
['875', '364'],
['1347', '445'],
['259', '798'],
['400', '98'],
['805', '425'],
['523', '100']]
```